# Can't create link on column to another page with common data

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

So, I have 2 tables: KLIJENT and PROGRAM. In table KLIJENT primary key is id_klijenta which is foreign key in table PROGRAM. I want to make a link that when I click on id_klijenta from KLIJENT it shows me rows from PROGRAM where id_klijenta from KLIJENT is equal to id_klijenta from PROGRAM.
Here is my report on KLIJENT:

[image: klijent]

When I click on id_klijenta which is 3, it shows me all rows from PROGRAM not only with id_klijenta=3. You can see it on this picture:

[image: program]

I made the link this way shown on picture:

[image: way I did it]

It doesn't work. I want to show only rows from PROGRAM where id_klijenta is equal to id_klijenta from KLIJENT. How to do that?

Comment: Hi Ivana, did you still need help with this or did Salim's help?

Answer (score 0):

In your program page make sure to have an application item (e.g. P9_id_klijenta).
Your program query's where clause shall include the page item such as:

```
where id_klijenta = :P9_id_klijenta
```

Then when you set the link under **Set Items** section include your column primary id from the query for KLIJENT and select the page item (P9_id_klijenta) in PROGRAM page to pass the value.